# Segfault when employing strtok to split my string (delimited by spaces) into a 2D array of strings, how to avoid?

Tags: c

I am writing a program, and I have a need for a 2D array of the different words found in a string. It takes the starting string from a linked list.

At the moment, this is what I have and it is offering a segfault:

```
int main () {
    char word_pal[120]; //max length needed is 120
    char *token;
    char pal_arr[64][120];
    int i = 0;
    strcpy(word_pal, header->name); //header->name is "string to be split"
    token = strtok(word_pal, " ");
    strcpy(pal_arr[i], token);
    while (token != NULL) {
        i++;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        strcpy(pal_arr[i], token);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have put some print statements throughout, and it seems to be the `token = strtok(NULL, " ");` line that is messing things up, but I cannot tell why.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: At some point `strtok` is going to return NULL, and then you call `strcpy` with that NULL pointer, which typically results in a seg fault. You need to remove the `strcpy` that is outside the loop. And the loop body should be in this order: `strcpy` first, followed by `i++`, followed by `strtok`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `strtok` returns `NULL`, The variable `token` will be `NULL`.
Then you using `token` (it might be `NULL`) as an argument for strcpy.

Comment: Typo `maight` -> `might`.